# Integration of Gupshup into Botpress

Tags: botpress

I am developing a bot in Botpress and we're thinking of integrating it into Gupshup, which appears not to be supported by the Botpress team (https://github.com/botpress/messaging/, https://botpress.com/docs/messaging-channels/supported-channels).

I would like to know if somebody has already developed something working and also some detailed information on how to integrate a new channel into botpress itself, if it's possible and how.

Comment: Maybe a more general question is if you can invoke Botpress by consuming an API. That way with some middleware receiving requests from Gupshup and consuming Botpress API the integration would be easy